# When typedef becames an actual type?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, typedef

During the program compilation there are three main stages:

1. Preprocessing (all `#include`, `#define`, etc. are replaced)
2. Compilation (producing object files)
3. Linking (object files are linked to executable)

My question regards to the `typedef`. As I can see in preprocessed file output, the `typedef`ed typed are not replaced by the actual types.

When it happens? Is it possible to get already replaced types?

Comment: what exactly is it you want to do? is your question just a general question or do you need to know to achieve something, if the latter describe your problem and we may be able to help better

Comment: I think it could be said that the typedef is "absorbed" at a semantic level (in the compiler), so to say. Thus it is treated by the compiler as a "native" type (more or less). Being it a language feature and not a preprocessor directive, it is normal that it is not replaced like it would be for a `#define`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I can see in preprocessed file output, the typedefed typed are not replaced by the actual types.

No, they are not, because they are just an alias of a type.

> When it happens? Is it possible to get already replaced types?

That is an implementation detail, but since the typedefs are needed to compile, then it is done in the compilation process. It is not possible to get the real types using compiler or preprocessor. The only way is to manually replace, or look into the code.

Answer (score 0):

short answer:  During compilation.
`typedef` is a construct which is evaluated and understood by the compiler, so compiler is the one that emits the code required to treat tyedef'ed data as the original type. AFAIK, how it does so is implementation defined rather Unspecifed. But it does all that is necessary is what matters.

Comment: Is there any way to know what is an original type? (Not just looking into the source by myself)

Comment: @Alex: You might want to examine the assembly code generated by your compiler to conclude on that.